# Control the split size with Avro Input Format in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I must read Avro record serialized in avro files in HDFS. To do that, I use the AvroKeyInputFormat, so my mapper is able to work with the read records as keys.

My question is, how can I control the split size? With the text input format it consists on define the size in bytes. Here I need to define how many records every split will consist of.

I would like to manage every file in my input directory like a one big file. Have I to use CombineFileInputFormat? Is it possible to use it with Avro?

Answer (score 0):

Splits honor logical record boundaries and the min and max boundaries are in bytes - text input format won't break lines in a text file even though the split boundaries are defined in bytes.

To have each file in a split, you can either set the max split size to Long.MAX_VALUE or you can override the isSplitable method in your code and return false.

Comment: The problem si different:in the inout folder I have so many avro files where each contains some avro objects. I have to consider all the input objects and set the limit of 3-4 avro object per split.

Comment: You want each task to only deal with 3-4 avro objects? How many objects does a file contain? What are the sizes of the objects?

Comment: Sorry, 3-4 was an example to say that I must control how many object are per split. I prefer to consider all the input as one fileonky yo split and I can't know the size of the objects because they can contain array too.

Comment: If the files already contain the number of objects you want to process in each split, then just override the isSplitable method in your code and return false.